# Ubuntu based distros wont install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Not really sure if I should be asking this here and I know I certainly don't have enough information for the community's help but I am going to let it fly.

I have a Lenovo v570 laptop, plenty of performance for Linux but I cannot get Ubuntu to install. I have an existing install of Windows 7 Pro from the OEM disc. My goal is to install Linux on the D drive and the OEM partition. I tried to modify those partitions using the installer repartition tool and that seemed to work but still failed to install. Here is the makeup of my drive.

[image: Drive Partition]
.

I wold like to have the option to dual boot the computer in either the Linux or Windows environment. My preferred distribution is Ubuntu and I tried to install the 12.04.3 version but received the following **Installation Failed** message box during the installation:

```
The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It 
may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean 
the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics 
suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement,
or  to move the system to a cooler environment.
```

[Here is the link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to the instructions I used from the Ubuntu site to find the USB ISO creator. I downloaded and used the [Pendrive Linux Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create the LiveUSB flash drive. The software will boot into a LiveCD as well as a LiveUSB flash drive.

I then tried 12.04.4 and then Linux Mint 16 and get the same response. Even occurs when I tried installing it in a Virtualbox. EDIT: I was able to install 13.10 on the Virtual Box.

I was however able in install Zorin OS 6 LTS which makes me wonder what am I doing differently with Zorin 6 that I'm not doing with Ubuntu.

I hate to ask this question but I am so new to Linux (5 days) I have no clue what to do. Any ideas why I seeing this issue?

Comment: Are you using the same USB stick for all of these? It does sound like a disk issue.

Comment: I created an installer using the instruction  for alternate installation methods. 1 USB stick per ISO build.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you can point to the actual "instructions for alternate installation methods" that you used -- is there a URL? When I look at Ubuntu.com I see "Alternate Installation" instructions for a CD and a bunch of different USB options: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Alternate_Installation

Comment: Here is the link to the instructions I used from the Ubuntu site: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: See my edits to the question: if that isn't accurate, plz re-edit to make it accurate.

Comment: @Amanda & bgw2go: what do you mean with "alternate"? The non-gui based installation, Debian-like? Or just a different way to install?
Thanks.